# Wearing a bracelet to remind me to be mindful

Tags: personal-practice, mindfulness

Wearing a bracelet to remind me to be mindful  ... is it a good idea ?

from previous attempt it seemed useful for a day maybe two but than i get used to wearing the bracelet and i dont notice im wearing it

What are your thoughts about doing this practice - is it useful ? are there other ways to remind yourself to be mindful ?

anything someone wants to add about this subject is appreciated

Answer (score 4):

> Wearing a bracelet to remind me to be mindful ... is it a good idea ?
>
> from previous attempt it seemed useful for a day maybe two but than i get used to wearing the bracelet and i dont notice im wearing it

I guess your past experience shows this is not very useful

> What are your thoughts about doing this practice - is it useful ? are there other ways to remind yourself to be mindful ?

Relying on external tools may not be the most optimal but if it helps why not.

> anything someone wants to add about this subject is appreciated

When your mind wonders away be extra mindful when you bring your attention back. Look at a few breaths with sustained attention. Do a few body scans with sustained attention.

When your mind goes you bring your mind back to an object. Similarly even when your mind is on the chosen object you can repeal the re direction of the mind to the object continuously as if when initially brining the mind to the object.

This practice will help make your mindfulness stick to the chosen object.

Also as a mode of preliminary practice you can:

- scan you body zig zag quickly alternating the side.
- quickly alternating at the base of each nostril

This helps you redirect your attention to an chosen object like the breath continuously after initially brining to attention to it. Once you have some reasonable practice just target a chosen object repeatedly, even though you mind is not wondering away. One your mind get "sticky" with the object you an stop the continuous redirection.

Answer (score 2):

Take what I'm about to write with a grain of salt, as I have never tried either the practice you ask about or the one I am about to recommend.

Modern psychology recognizes a phenomenon called sensory adaptation wherein unchanging sensory stimuli gradually lose their intensity to the organism.  For this reason, I'd say it makes sense that you stop noticing your bracelet after a time.

Thich Nhat Hanh, whose advice I often find quite useful, recommends using bells as a reminder to be mindful I believe.  For example, you could find a bell alarm for your smartphone and have it ring at various times throughout the day and at those times you could mindfully breath in and out three times as per Thich Nhat Hanh's advice.  I'd think this latter practice would not be subject to the same degree of adaptation induced loss of noticeability given that the corresponding stimulus is not constantly present.